# Conversion a Numeros Romanos Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hola soy nuevo en JS y estoy tratando de crear un conversor de números romanos y lo que realmente se me complica es tratar de verificar la resta de números por ejemplo el 4 (IV) ya que debería analizar la posición del String y en base a eso chequear el valor?? Recien acabo de editar la pregunta ya que actualice la funcion para revisar el numero anterior y lo logre solo que solo funciona para la letra V. Podria utilizar un regex para chequear los otros valores?? cualquier comentario o sugerencia sera bienvenida :)

```js
function checkValue(valor) {
      let numero = 0;

         switch (valor) {
          case 'I':
          numero  += 1;        
          break;
          case 'V':
          numero += 5;        
          break;
          case 'X':
          numero += 10;        
          break;
          case 'L':
          numero += 50;        
          break;
          case 'C':
          numero += 100;        
          break;
          case 'D':
          numero += 500;        
          break;
          case 'M':
          numero += 1000;        
          break    
          default:
            console.log('Hubo un error');
            break;
        }

        return numero;

    }

    var romanToInt = function(romano) {
      let resultado = 0;
      for (const r in romano) {      
         
        let regex = /([VXCDM])/;
         if(romano[r - 1] == 'I' && romano[romano.length -1] !== 'I'){
            resultado += checkValue(romano[r]) - 2;
         } else {
           resultado += checkValue(romano[r]);
         }     
       
      }
          console.log(resultado);
    };

    romanToInt('DIV');
```

Comment: Como solo se puede restar una cifra en numeros romanos, podrías mandar el siguiente valor de la cadena y calcular según ese valor. si es superior pues restas y si no sumas. tendrías que crear un array con los números y según el indice controlar cual es el de mayor valor o un objeto con 2 propiedades la letra y el valor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

como puse en el comentario anteriormente puedes probar de esta manera

```
var romanToInt = function(romano) {
    let resultado = 0;
    const letters = romano.split("");
    letters.forEach((x, index) => {
       if (index + 1 != letters.length){
           if(checkValue(x) >= checkValue(letters[index+1])){
              resultado += checkValue(x);
           }else{
              resultado -= checkValue(x);
           }
       }else {
          resultado += checkValue(x);
       }
   });
   return resultado;
};

console.log(romanToInt('MMMMDCCCXXXVVIV'));
```

Solo hay que comparar con el numero siguiente y si el valor del siguiente es superior pues restas, si no sumas